# Get a single date value from a date field on a node with entity_metadata_wrapper()

Tags: 7, datetime, entities

I want to retrieve a date value from a date field attached to a node with entity_metadata_wrapper.

So far:

```
$node_wrapper->field_tournament_date->value();
```

Provides an array. Not many other methods work. So, I have to do:

```
$date = $node_wrapper->field_tournament_date->value();
$start_date = format_date($date['value'], 'short');
```

Is there a cleaner way of getting the value of a date field without breaking it up like that?

Answer (score 5):

In these situations with meta_data_wrapper you could put the array-value before the value function, like this:

```
$date = $node_wrapper->field_tournament_date->value->value();
```

Answer (score 2):

If your server's running PHP 5.4 you could use:

```
$start_date = format_date($node_wrapper->field_tournament_date->value()['value'], 'short');
```

since [function array dereferencing](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing) has been added.

Other than that I don't think there's a way of reducing your code to be honest. If you're manipulating date fields a lot you might consider creating a small helper function, something like

```
function MYMODULE_format_date_field($value, $column = 'value', $format = 'short') {
  return format_date($value[$column], $format);
}
$start_date = MYMODULE_format_date_field($node_wrapper->field_tournament_date->value());
```

or similar. It's not the best but it might save a bit of time.

Comment: Yeah, dereferencing is a no-go. Not 5.4. I wish. That would be ultra convenient. I just figured there was some native method of retrieving it from a date field, without loading up a date wrapper. No manipulating values, just going for quick custom display renderings with no fuss.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following approach:

```
foreach ($node_wrapper->field_tournament_date->getIterator() as $date_wrapper) {
  // dpm($date_wrapper->getPropertyInfo() // to see what properties you have
  $start_date = $date_wrapper->value->value();
  $end_date = $date_wrapper->value2->value();
  $duration = $date_wrapper->duration->value();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:

```
$entity->field_date->get( 0 )->value->value( );
```

The call to get is needed because date fields are lists.